# How to make Pandas Groupby faster?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a large volum data

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(res)
groupedData = frame.groupby(['objectType','userId','actionType']).size()

(pd.DataFrame(data=groupedData)).to_excel(writer,'sheet2')
writer.save()
```

How can I accelerate it by using multiprocessing or parallel?